# Object methods vs functions and encapsulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In class-based object oriented languages one of the benefits of objects is encapsulation: every method of an object has access to the object's data.

In JavaScript this benefit of encapsulation doesn't seem to be the same because of the feature of `this`.

In the example below `method1` has access to `this` without additional binding, but `method2` does not.

Is there any reason to use an object method instead of a plain function in the example below if we need to `bind` both `method2` and `function2` in order to have access to `this.args` inside them?

```
// service declaration

function Service(args) {
    this.args = args;
}

Service.prototype.method1 = function(query) {
    ............
    let res1 = service2.get(query).map(this.method2.bind(this)); // option 1
    let res2 = service2.get(query).map(function2.bind(this));    // option 2
    ............
};

Service.prototype.method2 = function(data) {
    // use args from 'this'
}

function function2(data) {
    // use args from 'this'
}

// service use

let service = new Service(args);
service.method1(req.query).
```

Comment: what is _document(data)_? What is _service2_? Do you have a less contrived example? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I agree with the comment above - what is `document(data)` ?

Comment: The obvious advantage would be to invoke `service.method2()` instead of `function2.call(service)` when it's not necessary to be bound (where there is no big difference)

Comment: @Mathleti sorry, it was a typo: function(data)

Comment: @Bergi in my case `method2` / `function2` are invoked only from within other object methods, so in a sense they are used as private, not public

Comment: @kyrylkov: in that case, there's no reason to expose the function on the prototype.

Comment: @Bergi right.  so is it a general approach in JavaScript to have method prototypes only for 'public' methods, while having 'private' functionality as regular functions?  especially taking into account that explicit bind / call is required for these 'private' functions to have access to constructor `this`?

Comment: @kyrylkov: The general approach is to make as few things private as necessary :-) For an OOP design with methods (accessed as properties) the prototype is standard, but for (possibly private) static functions a functional approach, that uses an additional argument instead of `this`, gains popularity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should always use methods instead of using `bind(this)` because when you use external functions, you need to carry those along with that class. Why not just include them as a method on the class?

Also, I don't get the point of the `this.method2.bind(this)` call. `this.method2` is already bound to `this` because it is a property of `this`.

Assuming you know some ES6 from your `let` statement, you could write your code like this:

```js
class Service {
  constructor(args) {
    this.args = args;
  }
  method1(query) {
    let res1 = Service2.get(query).map(this.method2); //btw, what is Service2 here? Is it just an object with methods or does it need to be initialized?
  }
  method2(data) {
    //use data
  }
}
let service = new Service(args);
service.method1(req.query);
```

Comment: If I use `let res1 = Service2.get(query).map(this.method2)` without `bind` on `method2` defined via prototype, `this` ends up being `undefined` in `method2`

Is ES6 `class` behavior different?  (I'll check now)

Comment: I am on io.js and V8 and ES6 classes are not implemented yet.  So the bottom line is that with `method2` define via prototype I need `bind` to access proper `this`

Comment: @kyrylkov You can use 6to5 to transpile classes to pure ES5. And all methods of a class in ES6 have `this` bound correctly- I just checked with this dummy code: `
class Service {
  constructor(args) {
    this.args = args;
  }
  method1(query) {
    let res1 = [1, 2, 3].map(this.method2); //btw, what is Service2 here? Is it just an object with methods or does it need to be initialized?
    return res1;
  }
  method2(data) {
    return data * 2;
  }
}
let service = new Service({
  arg: 1
});
service.method1("data");`

Comment: that's a big plus of ES6 classes in this case